# Possible to annotate dictionary key?

Tags: swift

I have the following dictionary:

```
let myDict: [String: Any] = [
  "first": [
    "message": "qqq",
    "extras": ["task": "first"]
  ],
  "second": [
    "message": "www",
    "extras": ["task": "second"]
  ],
  "third": [
    "message": "eee",
    "extras": ["task": "third"]
  ],
]
```

Note how it’s annotated as `[String: Any]`. Yet Swift seemingly complains that the key themselves are not annotated:

```
/tmp/example.swift:2:12: warning: heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[String : Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional
  "first": [
           ^
/tmp/example.swift:6:13: warning: heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[String : Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional
  "second": [
            ^
/tmp/example.swift:10:12: warning: heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[String : Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional
  "third": [
           ^
```

Is it even possible to annotate the dictionary keys? What would satisfy Swift in this situation?

Comment: `[String: [String: Any]]` maybe?

Comment: It seems to work for me without any warning. It could be some problem with overall parentheses or something. Can you share the entire file here?

Comment: @nutz Update your Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misreading the warning. The compiler is talking about the *value*, not the key. The problem is that these values are themselves heterogeneous dictionaries:

```
[
  "message": "qqq",
  "extras": ["task": "first"]
]
```

That is a dictionary with string keys, but values of two different types. Thus this is a `[String: Any]`. So you need to *say* that:

```
let myDict: [String: [String: Any]] = [
```

Alternatively you might like to write this out in generic notation:

```
let myDict: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>> = [
```

It may seem that the compiler is being unnecessary picky here, but the idea is that previously the compiler was making an *assumption* in the attempt to infer the type here, and arriving at that assumption is costly. In fact, *type inference is expensive* except in the most simple cases. Array and dictionary literals are *always* worth annotating explicitly, because otherwise the compiler has to look at every single element. (If there are enough of them, the compiler will give up with the complaint that it can't infer the type in a reasonable time; you may have seen that error.) So the more you can take the time to annotate your types so that the compiler doesn't have to infer them, the faster your app will compile in Xcode.

Comment: For sake of completeness, the warning shown in Xcode has a "fix" that will change the line to `"first": [ "message": "qqq", "extras": ["task": "first"]] as [String: Any]`. Clearly declaring `myDict: [String: [String: Any]]` is better.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. Just so it’s absolutely clear, you’re saying that this hit in performance only affects the compile time, not the execution time correct? I’ll keep that in mind. I’ve been doing small CLI apps so that is not yet a problem.

Comment: Yes but it's best to get into good habits. And regardless of performance, Swift is moving towards abolishing the "accidental Any". This warning will be an error in Swift 6. So let's be ready.